# Icon isn't showing on the OnCreateOptionMenu

Tags: android

I have used this theme in my ChatActivity which looks like this-

```
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#009688</item>
</style>
```

This ChatActivity extends Activity.When i am creating OnCreateOptionMenu a call icon should show up in the menu.But itn't showing up.It remains under the three doted line. 
My menu xml is
**menu_conversation.xml** which is

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@mipmap/call_button"
    android:title="@string/call_button"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

In my ChatActivity class

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_conversation, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

How can i show this icon on the menu?

Comment: You said that your menu's filename is menu_concersion, but you inflated menu_conversation file.

Comment: try to return true; instead of  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)

Comment: I have tried that too. But it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: try adding this line to menu item `android:showAsAction="always"`

Comment: Since you are not using the ActionBarActivity, the attribute showAsAction should be available from the Android namespace. In short, have you tried leaving "android" instead of "app" before showAsAction?

Comment: It shows a error **Should use app:showAsAction with appcompat library with  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"** when using "android" instead of "app". @JDenais

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into this link ...this user also had a similar problem
[menu_icon_not_visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32195376/unable-to-add-action-buttons-to-my-action-bar-in-android-studio/32195510#32195510)

You need to add attribute orderInCategory to 1,2 etc

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I have tried this.Still not showing any icon in menu.

Comment: Did you orderInCategory attribute and what number or order u provided it ?

Comment: i provided like this **android:orderInCategory="1"**

Comment: I hope your are returning true from onCreateOptionsMenu() instead of super.onCreateOptionsMenu()

Comment: I am returning **return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);**

Comment: please return true instead of super.onCreateOptionsMenu()

Comment: can you tell how to can i change the position of this icon like now it showing at top-right. How to move this icon to some dp left? Is there any attribute?

Comment: use can do that via image ... tell the designer to give you a image with transparent space in the right 

or

you can add a transparent menu icon and when it gets clicked , do not parfoem any action